# How to enable On Screen keyboard when Scanner is connected to the Mobile phone

Tags: socketscan

If the scanner(Socket Mobile CHS Series 8 ) is ON and connected to the device the keyboard is not displayed as the input device becomes scanner. How can we handle this programmatically using Jquery as we need to show the device keyboard at some places?

Regards
Aman

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **No**

### Long answer

Based on your description you are using HID mode, which means as far as the mobile phone is concerned the scanner is a keyboard. Logically, you don't need an on-screen keyboard if you have a physical one, so the virtual keyboard is hidden.

#### Work around

- iOS and Android

  - Double click power button - the scanner will send a command to display the virtual keyboard if it detects a double click on the power button. Note: This is easier on the 7 series scanners
  - jQuery input widget - there are jQuery plugins for different input types (e.g. a calendar modal for selecting a date). Maybe you can find or write an input widget to suit your needs.
- Android only

  - Keyboard settings - certain versions of Android (4.2+) have the option to turn off the hardware keyboard. It's counterintuitive, but the physical keyboard will still work and the virtual keyboard will open on every input.

Comment: Hi Enrico, i tried to use scanner with sample app SingleEntry provided with SocketAPISdk but i am getting error -27 & then after few seconds -47. Can you give me any revised sample app link or give me any idea to connect scanner in SPP mode with my app. Thanks

Comment: The comments aren't the right place for this. Can you post a new question and tag it socketscan? Please include the IDE you are using, steps you took to open and setup Single Entry, plus the stacktrace